# Changing maintenance plan in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, backup, ssms, maintenance-plan

I have a maintenance plan that is set up to back up all of my 5 DB's every day. I do not need to backup them all, only part of them. I don't want to create a new job as my website is old and I don't want to make significant changes (moreover, I am not very familiar with SQL). I want to change the properties of this job to backup only certain DB's and didn't find my answer in google.

I added a screenshot of the task I want to modify. If any additional info is required in order to help me please tell me so.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming**, but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the off-topic and sorry if I shouldn't answer:
Right click on the "Back Up Database Task" node --> Edit --> General Tab
You could find there a list of databases so you can check/uncheck them